# Переименовывание файла на сервере

Tags: c#, сервер

Вот у меня закачен на сервере файл "файл.txt", и мне его надо без перекачки переименовать. Как я понял, надо использовать FTP, но как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё зависит от того, доступ по какому протоколу у вас есть к этому файловому хранилищу и что это за файловое хранилище.

Если на сервере операционка Windows и файл в "расшаренной" папке, ну или какой-то другой сервер с поддержкой [SMB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), то нет никаких проблем переименовать файл при помощи [System.IO.File.Move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218910/rename-a-file-in-c-sharp).

Если файловое хранилище доступно по протоколу **FTP**, то можно воспользоваться [FtpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026170/how-to-rename-a-file-after-upload):

```
var requestFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(
    new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServer + "/" + destination + "/" + fileName));
requestFTP.Proxy = null;
requestFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);

string newFilename = "<new file name>";
requestFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
requestFTP.RenameTo = newFilename;
requestFTP.GetResponse();
```

Comment: У меня сервер от ucoz. Подойдёт ли System.IO.File.Move для него?

Comment: @Minebot Честно говоря, я не знаю как ucoz предоставляет доступ к файловому хранилищу. Давайте ссылку на документацию.

Comment: @Eugene Сервер вроде CMS. А документация вот: http://manual.ucoz.net/ или это (я хз): http://api.ucoz.net/ru/manual#modules

Comment: @Minebot CMS это не протокол файлового хранилища, это Content Management System, обычно за этими словами скрывается некий пользовательский интерфейс управлением контентом чего-нибудь. Документацию я нашел сам: http://faq.ucoz.com/faq/21-1, можно использовать FTP.

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё заработало